# Why doesn't overriding "goog.ui.Control.handleMouseOver()" do anything?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I am trying to add a class to an instance of a subclass of `goog.ui.Button` when the user hovers over the button.

To this end, I overrode `handleMouseOver`:

```js
/**
 * Handles mouseover events.
 * @param {goog.events.BrowserEvent} e Mouse event to handle.
 * @override
 */
myapp.ui.Button.prototype.handleMouseOver = function(e) {
  goog.base(this, 'handleMouseOver', e);
  goog.dom.classes.add(this.getElement(), 'button-hover-state');
};
```

However, when I hover over the button, the class 'button-hover-state' is not added to the button. Why not? Chrome Console is not issuing any errors or warnings.

I could listen to an event and respond instead of overriding `handleMouseOver`, but shouldn't overriding this function alter what happens when the mouse enters the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your method `myapp.ui.Button.prototype.handleMouseOver` does not do anything is because mouse events are not being dispatched.

The default renderer used by `goog.ui.Button` is `goog.ui.NativeButtonRenderer`. The method `goog.ui.NativeButtonRenderer.prototype.createDom` calls `goog.ui.NativeButtonRenderer.prototype.setUpNativeButton_`, which in turn, calls:

```js
button.setHandleMouseEvents(false);
```

There are couple of approaches you could use to enable mouse events.

## Use the default button renderer and override `goog.ui.Component.prototype.render`

```js
/**
 * Renders the button.
 *
 * @param {Element=} opt_parentElement Optional parent element to render the
 *    component into.
 * @override
 */
myapp.ui.Button.prototype.render = function(opt_parentElement) {
  goog.base(this, 'render', opt_parentElement);
  this.setHandleMouseEvents(true);
};
```

## Use a different default renderer such as `goog.ui.ButtonRenderer`

```js
/**
 * My custom button.
 *
 * @param {goog.ui.ControlContent} content Text caption or existing DOM
 *     structure to display as the button's caption.
 * @param {goog.ui.ButtonRenderer=} opt_renderer Renderer used to render or
 *     decorate the button; defaults to {@link goog.ui.NativeButtonRenderer}.
 * @param {goog.dom.DomHelper=} opt_domHelper Optional DOM hepler, used for
 *     document interaction.
 * @constructor
 */
myapp.ui.Button = function(content, opt_renderer, opt_domHelper) {
  goog.base(this, content,
      opt_renderer || goog.ui.ButtonRenderer.getInstance(), opt_domHelper);
};
goog.inherits(myapp.ui.Button, goog.ui.Button);
```

When using `goog.ui.ButtonRenderer`, the CSS class `goog-button-hover` is automatically added to the button when the mouse hovers over the button and removed when the mouse leaves the button.